# Saving a txt file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text, save

I used pandas to replace the blank column spaces with nan in a txt file named A_B_1. How can I save this txt file as it is (blank spaces replaced with nan) to some path using pandas? I used the following code to read from it:

```
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_table("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Code/A_B_1.txt", sep="\s+", header=None).values
```

Comment: `data.to_csv('out.csv')`?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: I tried that before but got this error ('numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_csv') @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @Hrihaan Then do `pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(...)`

Comment: That worked, Thanks, but the issue is it is not being saved in the original format@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a 2D numpy array, you first convert it to a pandas data frame and then use `df.to_csv` and pass a tab separator:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('out.csv', sep='\t')
```